# with hunchentoot I cannot generate web pages

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am learning common lisp and trying to use hunchentoot to develop web apps.

With the code below I cannot manage to see the page defined in the retro-games function definition on the browser. I expect it to be generated by this function.

I write address as:

```
http://localhost:8080/retro-games.htm.
```

What displayed on the browser is `Resource /retro-games.htm not found`, the message and the lisp logo at the default page, that I could display. I can display the hunchentoot's default page.

```
(ql:quickload "hunchentoot")
(ql:quickload "cl-who")

(defpackage :retro-games
  (:use :cl :cl-who :hunchentoot))
(in-package :retro-games);i evaluate this from toplevel otherwise it does not change to this package.

(start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor :port 8080))

(defun retro-games ()
    (with-html-output (*standard-output* nil :prologue t)
      (:html (:body "Not much there"))
      (values)))

(push (create-prefix-dispatcher "/retro-games.htm" 'retro-games) *dispatch-table*)
```

The two loadings at the beginning were successful.

What am I missing?

Comment: UPDATE: i see when i start the server with the instance of the easy-acceptor class instead of above acceptor class as;

    (start (make-instance 'easy-acceptor :port 8080))

it works with all the other things on the above code.

Comment: Is this related to this recent question; http://stackoverflow.com/q/17777670/1281433 ?

Answer (score 2):

`Hunchentoot`'s API has changed a bit since that was written.  The behaviour of an `acceptor` assumed by that article is now found in `easy-acceptor`.  `Acceptor` is a more general class now, which you can use for your own dispatch mechanism, if you are so inclined.

So, instead of `(make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor #|...|#)`, use `(make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor #|...|#)`, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Default implementation of the `acceptor`'s request dispatch method, generates an HTTP Not Found error. So, you need to subclass `acceptor` class and redefine `acceptor-dispatch-request` method in subclass to make it actually dispatch requests. For example see [documentation](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#subclassing-acceptors).
`easy-acceptor` works because it defines `acceptor-dispatch-request` to use `*dispatch-table*` for routing.